# How to check if vectors are facing same direction

Tags: c++, vector, direction

I am working on a question where I am working within a right-handed coordinate system where the y-axis is straight up. I am supplied a structure that represents a 3-dimensional vector that looks like this:

```
struct vec{float x; float y; float z; };
```

I need to write a function that takes in a unit vector representing north and a unit vector represent a player's forward vector, and return if they are facing more north than south. Unfortunatly I have no idea where to go from here, I believe I have to do something like:

```
PlayerDirection = sqrt((PlayerVector.x *= PlayerVector.x)
                     + (PlayerVector.y *= PlayerVector.y)
                     + (PlayerVector.z *= PlayerVector.z));
```

But I do not know where to go from here. Any help/explanation would help, thanks.

Comment: `*=` should be replaced by `*`.

Comment: Look at [Dot_product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Answer (score 6):

apply a dot product to both vectors.  The dot product will be positive if the angle between both vectors is smaller than 90 degrees, and negative otherwise.

Comment: The dot-product is symmetrical, hence this approach does not work. Symmetrical means in this conntext, that it is impossible to evaluate if the real angle is 10° or 350°.

Comment: @Y.S In this context those angles are equivalent. OP want to "return if [the player is] facing more north than south".

Comment: @Y.S. that's irrelevant.  A north and south unit vectors are the same vector with the opposite direction, so the dot product with each vector will only differ in the result's signal.  Furthermore, 10 degrees and 350 degrees is the exact same angle, so both are equivalent in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

The formula you include (and which contains an error - the product is "*", not "*=") gives you the entity of the movement - the length of the vector. Which you already know, since it is a *unit* vector and therefore has length 1.

You need instead to perform the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) between the two vectors. You get 1 if the two unit vectors are completely aligned (parallel), -1 if they're antiparallel, and zero if they're normal to each other.

"More north than south" means that the scalar product is positive, so:

> return if they are facing more north than south

```
Alignment =  ((PlayerVector.x * NorthVector.x)
            + (PlayerVector.y * NorthVector.y)
            + (PlayerVector.z * NorthVector.z));

return (Alignment > 0);
```

## Questions

> What if I wanted to tell if it was facing east/west?

The dot product tells you **how much two vectors are aligned**. It is the same formula shown by Kevin Glasson, without the unit vectors norms since they are 1, and dividing by one doesn't change anything.

So, you can't use it to tell where a vector is facing *except in terms of another vector*. And that's why you're given the north vector; with the player vector alone you can't run a dot product. To tell whether the player is facing east, you need the east vector (or the west vector, and then take the opposite sign).

> So if the number comes back as say 35 it means it is facing more north than south but why?

Why it is so: you can find it explained on the Wikipedia page, the dot product is equal to the product of the two lengths by the cosine of their angle. Since the lengths are both 1, **it is just the cosine**. The cosine varies between 1 and -1 (so you can't ever get 35). When the cosine is 1, it means that the angle is zero and the vectors are aligned; when it is -1, they're opposite. A cosine of zero means the vectors are normal to each other, i.e. form an angle of 90°, and in this case it means that the player is facing *either* East, West, or Up, or Down - but it doesn't tell you *which*.

Comment: I don't understand what is going on with the value of Alignment. So if the number comes back as say 35 it means it is facing more north than south but why? What if I wanted to tell if it was facing east/west?

Comment: Would the downvoters care to explain what the problem with the answer is...? An answer can be usefully amended if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think what would work is taking the ['dot product'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of the vectors. Using the following form:

[image]

Where you would re-arrange for theta. This would give you the angle between the two vectors.

In my mind at least if the angle was 0 then you are pointing exactly north and if the angle were greater than 90 then you were facing more south.

I don't know exactly how you intend to use this, but this should work for being able to tell North from South in 3D space.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can use the dot-product to get the angle between 2 vectors. The formula is the following:

```
cos(phi) = (a * b) / (|a|*|b|)
```

Which converts to this:

```
phi = acos((ax*bx + ay*by + az * bz) / (sqrt(ax^2 + ay^2 + az^2)+sqrt(bx^2 + by^2 + bz^2)))
```

Now the dot product is symmetric, meaning: (1,1,1)*(2,2,2) gives you the same result as (2,2,2)*(1,1,1). Hence you have to add a further step. By adding a third vector, whose angle to the first given vector you do know, you can verify the true angle between the two vectors. Optaining this reference vector can be done by turning the first vector arround an axis, now to ensure it is a valid reference it has to be in the same plane as the vectors a and b.
This means that your axis to turn your first vector arround has to be orthogonal to vector 1 and 2, the vectorproduct of 2 vectors gives a vector orthogonal to both, so we will use the so obtained vector as axis.

```
axis = a x b
```

This is equal to:

```
axis = (aybz-azby, azbx-axbz, axby-aybx)
```

To turn a vector by a given amount arround an axis the following has to be done:

```
double R[3][3] = {};
            Vector axis = Axis.getUnitVector();
            double deg = degrees / 180 * M_PI;
            R[0][0] = axis.X * axis.X * (1 - cos(deg)) + cos(deg); R[0][1] = axis.X * axis.Y * (1 - cos(deg)) - axis.Z * sin(deg); R[0][2] = axis.X * axis.Z * (1 - cos(deg)) + axis.Y * sin(deg);
            R[1][0] = axis.Y * axis.X * (1 - cos(deg)) + axis.Z * sin(deg); R[1][1] = axis.Y * axis.Y * (1 - cos(deg)) + cos(deg); R[1][2] = axis.Y * axis.Z * (1 - cos(deg)) - axis.X * sin(deg);
            R[2][0] = axis.Z * axis.X * (1 - cos(deg)) - axis.Y * sin(deg); R[2][1] = axis.Z * axis.Y * (1 - cos(deg)) + axis.X * sin(deg); R[2][2] = axis.Z * axis.Z * (1 - cos(deg)) + cos(deg);
            double x = this->X * R[0][0] + this->Y * R[0][1] + this->Z * R[0][2];
            double y = this->X * R[1][0] + this->Y * R[1][1] + this->Z * R[1][2];
            double z = this->X * R[2][0] + this->Y * R[2][1] + this->Z * R[2][2];
```

The unitvector is defined as following:

```
e_a = (ax / sqrt(ax^2+ay^2+az^2),ay / sqrt(ax^2+ay^2+az^2),az / sqrt(ax^2+ay^2+az^2))
```

Using this new axis we can rotate our first vector a 90°. By calculating the angle between our reference and our second vector we can now evaluate the real angle between the first and second vector. If the angle to the reference is bigger than 90° the 2nd vector is in the 3rd or 4th sector or a cartesian coordinate system, meaning to get the real angle we'll have to substract our aquired angle between the first and the 2nd vector from 360°. If the angle to the reference it is smaller than 90° the calculated angle is the real angle.

Now there is another issue, what/where is north? If we know north we could just calculate the angle between north and the two vectors and the one with the smaller angle would be more north. This means there is no reason to evaluate a reference vector or build and apply the rotation matrix.

In case of a fixed north you could also project your vectors on a plane containing north, and simplify the calculations required.
Provide more information and I will edit this.

edit:/ since you provide the north and a player vector, just calculate the angle between them.